# How to change button background color as there are lots of buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, dom

I have created lots of HTML buttons, as the user presses on it, it should change the background color or do something to let user know about it. However, I don't create that event in the beginning.

Now I have troubles, should I add lots of instructions in every triggered event to change the color, or do I have some another SIMPLE approaches which are more convenient.

I want to create a public function which receives the `button id`, using it to control which button should be highlighted. Nevertheless, I don't know how to get the button id like this:

```
$("#upload").bind("click", function(){

 //I want to get the string 'upload'
 })
```

Any more convenient approach? I don't want to add lots and lots of instructions
for many buttons.

Comment: Have you considered using CSS for this ?

Comment: `this` inside the handler method points to the clicked button

Comment: @mohkhan  Actually, if I can get the button id, I would use it ~.css("background-color", "blue");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`this` inside the event handler methods will refer to the clicked button, so you can get the id using `this.id`.

```
var buttons = $(":button").bind("click", function(){
    buttons.not(this).css('background-color', '')
    $(this).css('background-color', 'blue')
})
```

This will change the background of the clicked button to blue

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/LQ6BM/)

But I may prefer to use a css class to do this

```
button {
    background-color: lightgrey;
}

button.active {
    background-color: blue;
}

var buttons = $(":button").bind("click", function(){
    buttons.filter('.active').removeClass('active')
    $(this).addClass('active')
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/LQ6BM/3/)

Comment: Only one button can be highlighted each time.

Comment: Hi, I create a separate JS file called `controlBtnColors.js` and its' content is  `var buttons= ...` But it can't work. I am pretty sure I include that js file. A little weird. As I use command line in Chrome it works...

Comment: Sorry, I got it. You are right. I use `$(document).ready(function(){});` to resolve this stupid issue. DOM elements need to bind the events after they are ready...

Comment: I haven't wondered that I can use `css class` design in my code. The css design is pretty.

Btw: Please keep the fiddle. I want to explore more, thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Is this what you want?

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/9Y8dE)

HTML

```
 <div data-role=page id=home>
              <div data-role=header>
                <h1>Location</h1>
              </div>

              <div data-role=content>

                    <a id="ButtonLocation" data-role="button" ><h4>Upload</h4></a>
              </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('#ButtonLocation').click(function() {
    alert($(this).text())
});
```

Answer (score -1):

With your specific question, if you want the ID, you'd do this:

```
$("#upload").bind("click", function(){
   var upload = $(this).attr('id'); //this is the id
})
```

The key is the .attr('id')

As other posters have mentioned, if all you are looking to do is change the background color, you don't even need this. However, if you want one function which handles only certain IDs you determine, you could even do something like this:

```
$("button").bind("click", function(){
   var thisID = $(this).attr('id'); //this is the id

   if (thisID == "upload") {
      $(this).css({"background":"black","color":"white"});
   }
});
```

Cheers, hope that helps.

Answer (score -1):

```
$(":button").bind("click", function(){
            iid=this.id;
                if(iid=="upload")
                {
                    $(this).css('background-color', 'blue')
                }
                else if(iid=="upload1")
                {
                    $(this).css('background-color', 'yellow')
                }
                else
                {

                }
            });
    });
```